# Phonegap opens external URL of third party library fullscreen

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm having this little issue with PhoneGap when playing around with it:

Whenever I open an external link on my iPhone, it goes fullscreen and there is no way back but terminate the app and start again. I've read some articles and think this could be easily fixed by just calling window.open (or navigator.app.loadUrl on Android).

However, the problem continues with 3rd party library. In particular, I'm using Google Maps and the widget has little links to "Terms of Use" and something else. Tapping this link will load the Google URL full screen again.

My question is, is there any global configuration/code to either modify the in-app web browser (add header, back button and so on) or open every external links on device's default browser?

Thanks for reading and helping :)

Comment: Did you take a look at the InAppBrowser? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: Yes I did, normally they require to open the link by a javascript function which is feasible as I cannot interfere in third party call. The only possible solution I can think of is to add listener to prevent InAppBrowser to open, then open it on device browser instead. But I'm still stuck at open links on device browser. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just checked, there is no event fired before the link is opened, that means I can only detect the event after InAppBrowser is started. Another option is to listen to 'loadstart', then close the InAppBrowser and reopen it with custom options. However, I feel that this is not the right way to do. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First you study about [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html).

InAppBrowser open with close(done) button . This is not working means you also use [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser).

[Reference 1](http://www.packtpub.com/article/configuring-the-childbrowser-plugin)
[Reference 2](http://mobileappstechies.blogspot.in/2012/09/installing-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios.html)